# Spring Boot ClassCastException when iterating over lists of child classes with same parent, annotated many-to-many

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm building a REST api in java using Spring Boot 3.1.1 with Maven that retrieves information about Movies, their Directors and Writers. Movie class is a child of Media class, and has a many-to-many relationship with Director and Writer classes, whom both extend the same Person class.

After retreiving MovieJPA objects from repository i get ClassCastException when iterating over DirectorJPA and WriterJPA lists. I can print them in console one after another using System.out.println, suggesting that their data is retreived from database, but only when i iterate over them one after another, i get the exception and i don't know why.

**Media parent class:**

```
@Entity(name = "Media")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "media")
public class MediaJPA implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //Other attributes
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "media_directors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "media_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "director_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id"))
    private List<DirectorJPA> directors = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "media_writers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "media_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "writer_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id"))
    private List<WriterJPA> writers = new ArrayList<>();

    //constructors; getter and setter methods

}
```

**Movie child class:**

```
@Entity(name = "Movie")
@Table(name = "movie")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "media_id")
public class MovieJPA extends MediaJPA {

    private Integer length;

//constructors; getter and setter methods

}
```

**Person parent class:**

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "person")
public class PersonJPA implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //Other attributes

    //constructors; getter and setter methods

}
```

**Director child class:**

```
@Entity(name = "Director")
@Table(name = "director")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public class DirectorJPA extends PersonJPA{
    
}
```

**Writer child class:**

```
@Entity(name = "Writer")
@Table(name = "writer")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public class WriterJPA extends PersonJPA {

}
```

As i've learned, spring boot is supposed to provide implementation for my JPA class:

```
@Repository
public interface IMovieRepository extends JpaRepository<MovieJPA, Long>{
    
}
```

Problem arrises in my service class:

```
@Service
public class MovieService {

    @Autowired
    private IMovieRepository movieRepo;

    public void getAllMoviesTest() {
        for (MovieJPA jpa : movieRepo.findAll()) {

            //this works
            System.out.println(""+jpa.getDirectors());
            System.out.println(""+jpa.getWriters());

            //Both of these for loops together won't work, but alone work
            for (DirectorJPA director : jpa.getDirectors()) {
                System.out.println("Director: " + director.getFirstName() + " " + director.getLastName());
            }
            for (WriterJPA writer : jpa.getWriters()) {
                System.out.println("Writer:" + writer.getFirstName() + " " + writer.getLastName());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

After executing code above i get the following exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class DirectorJPA cannot be cast to class WriterJPA`

My dependencies are listed below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I tried searching the internet for answers, but i found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try to update the mapping to

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = DirectorJPA.class)
@JoinTable(
        name = "media_directors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "media_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "director_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id"))
private List<DirectorJPA> directors = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = WriterJPA.class)
@JoinTable(
        name = "media_writers",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "media_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "writer_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id"))
private List<WriterJPA> writers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it still yields the same exception. If i enable spring.jpa.show-sql, hibernate generated sql shows correct queries being executed, but only after iterating over these lists i get ClassCastException: WriterJPA cannot be cast to class DirectorJPA